# Elementary inequality with norms

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces

Is it reasonable to hope the validity of an inequality of this form, where $H$ can be any separable Hilbert space

$$\forall \alpha \geq 0 \, \exists \gamma \geq 0: || x - \alpha y|| \leq \gamma || x -y ||, \quad \forall x,y\in H$$

If not, any counterexample to get an intuition of what goes wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha\neq 1$, then it fails for $x=y$, since the right hand side is $0$, and the left hand side is positive.

Comment: oh, gosh, such a stupid question I asked...quite embarassing.
Thanks a lot and sorry for the waste of time :)

Comment: @Matt no worries.